# I am trying to use log4j2.xml file to load into my project which is in d drive how can i do it?

Tags: log4j2

Loading  log4j2.xml file which is in D drive into my application how can i do it?
Like log4j DOMConfigurator is there any way in log4j2.

I am editing because i dont get the perfect answer :

As i am using System Property 
Variable name : sys_logroot
Variable value : D:\user\gouse

In this directory i have my log4j2.xml file.I am trying to use this log4j2.xml file in my application i am not able to load this xml file and no log files are created to my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the location of the log4j2.xml config file with a system property: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location

No DomConfigurator required.